# Prove $f(x)\equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, smooth-functions

> Assume $f$ is $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb R$, and satisfies
>
> 1. There exists $M>0$ such that for any non-negetive integer $n$ and any $x\in\mathbb R$, $\left|f^{(n)}(x)\right|\leqslant M$
> 2. $\displaystyle f\left(\dfrac{1}{m}\right)=0, m\in \mathbb Z^{+}$
>
> Prove: $f(x)\equiv 0$ on $\mathbb R$.

I have no ideas about this problem. How can we make use of the second claim? Does it implies that we can firstly prove $f(x)=0$ at every rational numbers and then extend to the whole real numbers?

Comment: Can you use the first condition to prove that $f$ is not just smooth but analytic? In other words can you show that the Taylor series for $f$ converges to $f$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$? After doing this can you try and work out what the Taylor coefficients must be?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I discovered that I answered the same question one and a half year ago. I also voted to close your question as a duplicate.